# How do I modify the settings of the coordinates of the canvas using "Turtle" in Python 2.7.9?

Tags: python, math, canvas, turtle-graphics, trigonometry

I would like my turtle to draw a sine curve in the range of y=(-1, 1).
It works properly, but the size of the drawing is very tiny. If I multiply y by 50, it looks pretty good, but my task is to represent y=(-1, 1), so multiplying the y values is not an option.

I would like to modify the display settings of the canvas, e.g. y=(-1, 1) should be 300px. I hope you understand what I mean. Thanks in advance for your help!

[Here is my code so far.](http://pastebin.com/gdy0HxCd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y = 50*(math.sin(math.radians(x)))
```

with x in the range from min to max will of course produce the corresponding graph, if (min,max)=(0,300) then from sin(0) to sin(300*pi/180).

```
(x-min)/(max-min)
```

will produce a variable in the range of 0 to 1

```
-1+2*(x-min)/(max-min)
```

correspondingly a variable in the range from -1 to 1.

So what you want is

```
y = 50*(math.sin(-1+2*(x-min)/(max-min)))
```

---

Update after comment: Why not set unit=150, so that, using the typical screen coordinates, you can use directly `y=math.sin(x)`

Or set the user coordinate system such that

```
(lower left upper right)=(-1.2 -1.2 1.2 1.2 )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there is a little misunderstanding, so I've drawn a picture of what I meant to ask. [link](http://i59.tinypic.com/33ynmv9.png)

Is there any possibilities to set this up?

Comment: Is this the turtle module with `turtle.setworldcoordinates(llx, lly, urx, ury)`?